# Docker Compose ECS Load Balancer not configured

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have a docker-compose.yml file like this:

```yaml
version: "3"

x-aws-vpc: 'vpc-xxx'
x-aws-loadbalancer: 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxx:loadbalancer/app/xxx'

services:
  api:
    image: image/xxx
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl --fail http://localhost/health || exit 1"]
    environment:
      - PORT=80
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    expose:
      - 80
    depends_on:
      - redis
    deploy:
      x-aws-autoscaling:
        min: 1
        max: 4
        cpu: 75
    networks:
      - alb

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 6379
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    networks:
      - alb

networks:
  alb:
    external: true
    name: "sg-xxx"
```

I created a load balancer myself so it would get created in specific subnets.

When I run the command `docker compose up`, the ECS cluster gets created correctly but there is no link created between the Load Balancer and the services. When updating the service, it says:

> Elastic load balancing not configured. Load balancing settings can only be set on service creation.

I also tried to create a `Target Group` manually, but still nothing gets added to the targets.